# How to pool average predictions from a multinomial regression per category in R

Tags: prediction, imputation, r-mice, multinomial, r-marginaleffects

I want to obtain pooled average predictions per level of a categorical variable using a multinomial regression on multiple imputed data. My problem is that the `pool()` function seems to collapse all the levels to produce one single estimated average prediction instead of keeping the stratification per category. Here is a step-by-step example:

1. Using `rent` data from `library(catdata)` I create 2 categorical variables

```
library("tidyverse")
library("catdata")
library("mice")
library("nnet")
library("marginaleffects")
data(rent)

rent<-rent%>%
  mutate(rent_cat=factor(case_when(
    rent<389.95~"Low price",
    rent>=389.95&rent<700.48~"Medium price",
    rent>=700.48~"High price"
  )))%>%
  mutate(size_cat=factor(case_when(
    size<53~"Small",
    size>=53&size<83~"Medium",
    size>=83~"Big"
  )))
```

2. Run a multiple imputation by chained equation

```
micerent<-mice(rent,m=3)
```

3. Obtain average prediction per level of a categorical variable

To be noted, based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74467553/obtaining-predictions-from-a-pooled-imputation-model) it is better to build a function to extract predicted probabilties and to apply it to our imputed datasets in a complete format. I'm using the `avg_predictions` following suggestion from `marignaleffects` [package tutorial](https://marginaleffects.com/vignettes/predictions.html#multinomial-models).

```
fit_reg <- function(dat) {
  mod <- multinom(rent_cat~ size_cat,data=dat)
  out <- avg_predictions(mod,type="probs",by="size_cat")
  return(out)
}

micecompleterent<- complete(micerent, "all")

model<-lapply(micecompleterent, fit_reg)
```

4. Pool the average predictions

There, instead of producing average prediction estimation per levels of `size_cat`, it seems to collapse all the stratified averages to give one pooled average prediction.

```
summary(pool(model),conf.int=T)
```

[image: Pooled results]

I also tried using `newdata=datagrid(size_cat=c("Big","Medium","Small")` in the `predictions` function from `marginaleffects` package but the result is the same:

```
fit_reg_response <- function(dat) {
  multinom(rent_cat~ size_cat,data=dat)
  out <- predictions(mod,newdata=datagrid(size_cat=c("Big","Medium","Small")))
  return(out)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. Internally, to combine results from different model objects, `mice::pool` calls the `tidy()` function on all objects. It expects the output of `tidy()` to be a data.frame with a `term` column, but `tidy` does not return such a column in this case, because there is not a robust and general way to say what a “term” is in the context of average predictions.
2. For good (but boring and irrelevant) reasons, `tidy()` returns a one-row average estimate when applied to the output of `avg_predictions()`

There is not a super straightforward way to solve this, but here's a workaround:

1. Assign a custom class name to the output of your `fit_reg()` function.
2. Define a `tidy()` S3 method which creates the `term` column you want, based on the row identifiers you care about.

## Old code

```r
library("tidyverse")
library("catdata")
library("mice")
library("nnet")
library("marginaleffects")
data(rent)

rent<-rent%>%
  mutate(rent_cat=factor(case_when(
    rent<389.95~"Low price",
    rent>=389.95&rent<700.48~"Medium price",
    rent>=700.48~"High price"
  )))%>%
  mutate(size_cat=factor(case_when(
    size<53~"Small",
    size>=53&size<83~"Medium",
    size>=83~"Big"
  )))

micerent <- mice(rent, m = 3, seed = 1024)
```

## New code

```r
fit_reg <- function(dat) {
    mod <- multinom(rent_cat ~ size_cat, data = dat, trace = FALSE)
    out <- avg_predictions(mod, type = "probs", by = "size_cat")
    # the next line is key
    class(out) <- c("custom_class", class(out))
    return(out)
}

micecompleterent <- complete(micerent, "all")

model <- lapply(micecompleterent, fit_reg)
tidy.custom_class <- function(x, ...) {
    # create a row identifier
    transform(x, term = paste0(group, size_cat))
}

summary(pool(model), conf.int = TRUE)
#                 term     estimate    std.error   statistic       df
# 1      High priceBig 6.131852e-01 0.0211548249 28.98559586 2041.778
# 2   High priceMedium 1.867514e-01 0.0122504868 15.24440754 2041.778
# 3    High priceSmall 2.399958e-06 0.0000685316  0.03501973 2041.778
# 4       Low priceBig 5.283582e-02 0.0097171507  5.43737813 2041.778
# 5    Low priceMedium 1.650216e-01 0.0116685744 14.14239902 2041.778
# 6     Low priceSmall 6.223208e-01 0.0214465891 29.01723885 2041.778
# 7    Medium priceBig 3.339790e-01 0.0204863976 16.30247432 2041.778
# 8 Medium priceMedium 6.482270e-01 0.0150108250 43.18396572 2041.778
# 9  Medium priceSmall 3.776768e-01 0.0214465633 17.61013157 2041.778
#         p.value         2.5 %       97.5 %
# 1 5.135684e-155  0.5716979181 0.6546724948
# 2  8.872206e-50  0.1627266590 0.2107761683
# 3  9.720674e-01 -0.0001319992 0.0001367991
# 4  6.054466e-08  0.0337792608 0.0718923850
# 5  2.168686e-43  0.1421380844 0.1879051861
# 6 2.679125e-155  0.5802613238 0.6643802735
# 7  2.898326e-56  0.2938025529 0.3741553884
# 8 5.330330e-290  0.6187888240 0.6776650781
# 9  9.846943e-65  0.3356173772 0.4197362256
```

Comment: FYI, I opened two feature requests on Github. Once they are fulfilled and the package reaches CRAN, the task you describe should be a lot easier. https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/marginaleffects/issues/983  https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/marginaleffects/issues/982